# Help with looping for an array with key and value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make this function that extracts text from html for multiple steps but I cant figure out how to make a loop form it.

This is the task. I have this array

```
$arr = array("<div>" => "</div>", "<p>" => "</p>", "<h3>" => "</h3>");
```

The existing working function `cut($a, $b, $c)` that gets the content in between in this case `$a = "<div>", $b="</div>" and $c = the html`.

What i am trying to do is to make this:

- Step 1 - cut from div to div
- Step 2 - foreach results from step1,
  cut from p to p
- Step 3 - foreach results from step2,
  cut from h3 to h3
- Step n where n is array length.

Although I know that I can use foreach to get the results and apply step two, I cant generalize this.

**EDIT**

I have an existing function called `cut` that has been described above. I want to create a new function called `cutlayer($arr, $html)` where $arr is arr from above. I need the cutlayer function to use the cut function and do the following steps mentioned above but I cant figure out how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear what you want, please could you give an example of the input, and desired output?

Comment: you wrote a function and do not know how to use it?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: I have edited the original question. Is that any clearer now?

Comment: You'd better post your existing `cut()` function so we can see how you're trying to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself the trouble and use a toolkit designed for parsing HTML.  PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is made for these tasks.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div");

// Get the inner contents of all divs, for example
foreach ($divs as $div) {
  echo $div->nodeValue;
}
```

Unless this is homework and you were instructed to use your array matching method....

Comment: I guess but DomDocument wont help me cut between specific segments for example just between "</span> and "<br>" which my cut function can but I just cant figure out how to incorporate it to the loop

Comment: @Kartik DOM can very much do that

Comment: I suppose I didnt mention it but my original question still states that I am not sure about how to make that function because I cant figure out how to design the loops. I am not looking for extracting just html in general. The inputs can be like <div> and </div> then "class='foo' >" and "/b>" then "Welcome" & "here" the `cut` function can already take care of what to extract but I cant figure out how to start using the array